# How to add new data to the dictionary

Tags: python

I designed a small python program
If the student's name is entered, one can
check their grade.

My problem is if I enter the student name and if it
cannot be found in the dictionary data, I must add a new student name to the dictionary. (using If statement)

The system immediately allows the user to enter a new piece of grade data and
the new student's name and grade data is added to the dictionary
How to design and achieve it?
I hope to achieve

The first:

```
Enter student name: amy
Student score: 85
Dictionary content: {"amy":85,"lisa":93,"jason":67,"}
```

The second type:

```
Enter student name: sherry
Enter student score: 90
Dictionary content: {"amy":85,"lisa":93,"jason":67,"sherry":90}
```

Add new student name and student score to the list
My code

```
stu=input("Enter student name:")
score={"amy":85,"lisa":93,"jason":67,"}
if stu==None:
    sco=int(input("Enter student score"))
else:
   print("Student score:",score.get(stu))
```

Comment: It is a dictionary, not list.

Comment: thanks for your reminder
I have re-edited

Answer (score 1):

There were some more syntax error as well and its not list its dictionary

```
stu=input("Enter student name:")
sco=int(input("Enter student score"))
score={"amy":85,"lisa":93,"jason":67}
score[stu]=sco#This is how you add an element to the dictionary
print(score)
```

Output

```
Enter student name:sachin
Enter student score98
{'amy': 85, 'lisa': 93, 'jason': 67, 'sachin': 98}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
students = {"amy": 85, "lisa": 93, "jason": 67}

student_name = input("Enter student name: ")

if student_name in students:
    print(students[student_name])
else:
    try:
        score = int(input("Enter student score: "))
        students[student_name] = score
    except ValueError as e:
        print('The score should be a number.')
print(students)
```